# Xcode 7.2.1 Making a Reset Button using a Button with Swift

Tags: swift, button, xcode7, viewcontroller

I am trying to make a reset button for my app that will reset the UI to the original state.  I have made a UIButton and linked it to the ViewController, but I have no idea where to go from here.  I tried using the following code:

```
@IBAction func resetToOriginalState(sender: UIButton) {
    self.resetToOriginalState (sender: UIButton)
}
```

It gave me the following error:

> Editor placeholder in source file

Sorry if there may be an obvious answer, but I am very new to Swift and Xcode.

Is there any other way to create a reset button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

> Editor placeholder in source file

Is because you are calling a function with the UIButton Class name instead of the actual button.

```
@IBAction func resetToOriginalState(sender: UIButton { 

    // this line is wrong, you shouldn't have UIButton in here
    self.resetToOriginalState (sender: UIButton)

    // the line should read
    self.resetToOriginalState (sender: sender)
}
```

This way, you are passing the actual button into the function that was passed to `resetToOriginalState`

Comment: Thank you!  This really helped Scriptable; I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have too `IBAction` for the same button, check how many time you have `@IBAction func resetToOriginalState(sender: UIButton)` in your code and remove the references from the references Interface list to clean it, should there be only one :

[image]

Comment: I have two instances of @IBAction in my code, once for this reset button and another for a different button.  However, I need to keep both of them in order for my app to function.  Is there anyway to create a reset button?

Comment: I meant it should there be only one ibaction both in code and in references interface list to button, so if you have 2 buttons each button must have these 2 aspect (code and references link).

Answer (score 0):

It depends what is in the scene and what do you need to reload. As far is I know you can't really segue a ViewController to itself, but here are few options:

1. Try to add `loadView()` when the button is pressed
2. Duplicate the view controller, and segue between the two. (might be risky and create more work)
3. Reset your variables to their initial state when the button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

You should give us more detail because this is implementation specific.

Nevertheless, it's not very clean, but depending on the architecture of your code, you might be able to generate a new instance of your view controller, destroy the current one, and present the new one.